# Ubuntu 22.04 bluetooth unable to pair any devices

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth

Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
kernel version 6.2.0-26-generic
Motherboard Z790 Aorus Elite Ax bluetooth 5.3

I tried multiple solutions, but none of them worked. I already installed bluez-tools and blueman.

bluetooth status information:

[image: bluetooth status info]